# How to observe Ramadan on the ISS

Tags: ramadan

Consider that the [International Space Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station) orbits the Earth in about 92 minutes. So the daylight period on the ISS is about 46 minutes, followed by 46 minutes of night. How would a Muslim on the ISS observe Ramadan? Would he fast for 46 minutes, 18 times per day? Or would he fast as per the time in e.g. Mecca or his home city?

Inspired by a comment on [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117962/how-to-observe-shabbat-on-mars).

Comment: Fasting itself isn't a big issue since travelers aren't required to fast and can make up their fast later. Salah is probably the bigger issue. Interestingly, the Malaysian government Islamic agency compiled guidelines for this and other issues when they sent their first astronaut, Sheikh Muszaphar
Shukor, to space: https://www.wired.com/images_blogs/wiredscience/files/a_guideline_ibadah_at_iss.doc

Comment: @TheZ: Thank you! Does the paper address the facing towards Mecca for prayer, another thing that I wanted to check? All I'm getting from that site is a message `Wired.com Sorry, something has gone wrong.` and that looks like a server error, not a browser error.

Comment: It does address that. I don't know why the link isn't working. Just search "A Guideline of Performing Ibadah (worship) at the International Space Station (ISS)" on Google. It should be in the first few results.

Comment: ‎‎‎‎‎T‎‎‎‎h‎‎‎a‎‎‎n‎‎‎k‎‎‎ ‎‎‎y‎‎‎o‎‎‎u‎‎.‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎‎‎‎  ‎‎